# Adjust cell height to image cell height within WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In WPF when using a DataGrid, I have an Image and various text fields. When I select a row, the selection looks ugly because the text cell heights are the same size as each other but are different to the image which is dynamic depending on the width of the image's grid column width.

In otherwords, the blue background colour that you get upon selection is quite large on the image cell as it is for the others as I show in the image below:

[image]

The DataGrid is just being constructed right now so it is very simple. I am just not sure of the easiest, cleanest, minimal code approach (if there is such a thing with WPF!). Here is the xaml for it so far:

```
<DataGrid Margin="10,52,10,10" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="MainGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentData}" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFBFBFBF" VerticalGridLinesBrush="White" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SKU" Binding="{Binding SKU}" />
        ...
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" Binding="{Binding Label}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

So, over to the WPF gurus. I have hunted high and low and haven't found something that seems to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear I found the solution. It was quite simple really, as I simply used DataGridTemplateColumn for each text field and put a TextBlock inside. This resolved the selection and the selection effect filled the whole cell due to the way the TextBlock filled the available space. I used VerticalAlignment to center the text and then it looked much much better as shown below:

[image]

For completion, here is the xaml:

```
<DataGrid Margin="10,52,10,10" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="MainGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentData}" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFBFBFBF" VerticalGridLinesBrush="White">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SKU" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SKU}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        ...
        ...
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Label" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

There is probably a much better way using styling and what not but this worked quite nicely without any code behind. Simples!?